# Is there a way to check, why the garbage collector isn't collecting a class instance in C#?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

This is a more general question that came up, because I have an instance of a viewmodel class, which - at least as far as I know - should be destroyed after I close the corresponding window.

I know, the garbage collector doesn't collect the instance as long as there are still some references to other alive class instances, right?

Question is: can I somehow ask the cg about the current status of an instance and why, or why not it is collecting it? Meaning, in my specific case, is there a way that the GC tell me for example, class instance xyz still holds reference to abc, therefore isn't collected?

Comment: You can do this with windbg / sos, using `!GCRoot`. That's probably more effort to set up than it's worth, though. The GC won't collect your ViewModel until it actually needs to.

Comment: What makes you _think_ it isn't being collected? Why do you care? This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .

Comment: @canton7 Hmm, so nothing I can do within my code? What is the criteria for "it actually needs to"?

Comment: @RolandDeschain It's complex. There are literally books on the subject. At a very high level, it won't collect objects until it needs the memory

Comment: @mjwills I simply put code into the destructor and checked if and when it executed. Is that a wrong approach? In my case it doesn't really matter if the viewmodel is collected, ie. I don't really have a problem. It just made me curious, how these things work...

Comment: @RolandDeschain The short answer is you shouldn't put code in the destructor. Putting code in the destructor is almost always wrong (as in - I have literally never done it in my entire time of working in C#). If you are asking this question, you definitely 100% should not be putting code in the destructor. _Regardless, if you aren't hitting the destructor (finalizer) then there is almost certainly a reference to the object somewhere._

Comment: @mjwills OK, I should clear things a bit: I was curious to know when the destructor was called, therefore I put a simple console.writeline() in it to check. Normally, I don't really touch the deconstructor. As mentioned before, OP is more of a general question, there is not really a specific coding problem here.

Comment: You may find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017681/garbage-collection-guarantees of interest.

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a read!

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/ is an approachable starting point. cbrumme's old blog posts are the gold standard. Regardless - you shouldn't be writing finalizers. :)